# Blank page when loading jsondata from textfile

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to load names from a html-file consisting of json-data. The problem is that the page is blank/white and no error message in the firefox debugger.

the test.html and persondb.html is on the same server.

**test.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JSON Exempel</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="person-lista">

</ul>

<script>

$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mywebbpage.com/ajax/persondb.html", // not the realname
    data: {
        limit: 5,
        name: 'ra'
    },

    success: function (response) {

        var personArray = response.personer;
        for(var i=0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            var person = personArray[i];
            $('#person-lista').append('<li>' + person.fnamn + '</li>');
        }
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**persondb.html**

```
{
"personer": [{
    "fnamn": "RACHELLE",
    "enamn": "ZWIEFELHOFER",
    "epost": "rachelle.zwiefelhofer@somefakedomain.nu"
}, {
    "fnamn": "RACQUEL",
    "enamn": "JOH",
    "epost": "racquel.joh@somefakedomain.nu"
}, {
    "fnamn": "RAE",
    "enamn": "BRAVARD",
    "epost": "rae.bravard@somefakedomain.nu"
}, {
    "fnamn": "RAFAEL",
    "enamn": "SAGASTUME",
    "epost": "rafael.sagastume@somefakedomain.nu"
}, {
    "fnamn": "RAISA",
    "enamn": "REINES",
    "epost": "raisa.reines@somefakedomain.nu"
}]
}
```

is the persondb.html not formatted correctly? is that the reason? When loading the persondb.html in a browser it look likes the following

```
{ "personer": [{ "fnamn": "RACHELLE", "enamn": "ZWIEFELHOFER", "epost": "rachelle.zwiefelhofer@somefakedomain.nu" }, { "fnamn": "RACQUEL", "enamn": "JOH", "epost": "racquel.joh@somefakedomain.nu" }, { "fnamn": "RAE", "enamn": "BRAVARD", "epost": "rae.bravard@somefakedomain.nu" }, { "fnamn": "RAFAEL", "enamn": "SAGASTUME", "epost": "rafael.sagastume@somefakedomain.nu" }, { "fnamn": "RAISA", "enamn": "REINES", "epost": "raisa.reines@somefakedomain.nu" }] }
```

Or is it problem with the "same origin policy" ? But the files is on the same server (same folder)

Comment: any error in the developer console (F12 in chorme and firefox)?

Comment: @GummaMocciaro - no errors at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON before you can access it in your loop -

```
success: function (response) {

    var res = JSON.parse(response);
    var personArray = res.personer;
    for(var i=0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
        var person = personArray[i];
        $('#person-lista').append('<li>' + person.fnamn + '</li>');
    }
}
```

Comment: yes correct - but the absolute url-string made the browser to block the request based on the "same origin policy". By just shortening the string to "persondb.html"  it worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON, as EatPeanutButter mentioned, or you have to send a correct Content-Type (application/json) with the response of your html-page.
Your JSON is well formed.